# How to set layout margin on Android Studio 3.4?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

Trying to do this [android tutorial](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-training-create-an-activity/index.html?index=..%2F..android-training#4),

> Drag a Plain Text (EditText) element from the Palette pane to the
>   bottom of the layout, and add constraints to the left side of the
>   layout, the bottom of the layout, and the left side of the Send
>   Button. Set its attributes in the Attributes pane as follows:
>   Attribute
>
> Value
>
> id 
>   editText_main
>
> Right margin 
>   8
>
> Left margin 
>   8
>
> Bottom margin 
>   16

But I do not see a way to set the layout margin. When I select the editText_main and input 8dp into the layout_marginLeft, and press Enter or Tab, the number 8dp disappears. It was swallowed without a burp.

[image: android studio 3.4]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was not obvious, but I right clicked and then selected the Constrain menu and added constraints. Then I went into Attributes and it allowed me to modify the current value.
It seems like a design bug.

Answer (score 0):

I'd advise you not to use the drag pane only, Some features are much easier with the xml editor

Goto you xml file add margins like this.

```
<EditText
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp" />
```

Comment: but the tutorial said to set it in the Attributes pane. `Set its attributes in the Attributes pane as follows: Attribute`

Answer (score 0):

It is not a bug, a constraint layout child CANNOT have a child with margins because it has a set position (if you just drag and drop it from the palette), the position wont change no matter what, so adding margins is useless, when its constrained those margins become useful because lets say i constraint a button to the left but i don't want it completely to the left, so lets add a marginLeft of 8 dp, in that case it is relevant to have a margin thats why the editor wasn't letting you add them until you constrained it.

You can see this in the "Text" tab, the position is absolute, margins are useless when the position is absolute. So the editor prevents you from adding them.

Whenever you add a constraint to it the editor gets rid of the absolute position and lets you add margins.

[image]

Maybe your tutorial didn't specify what layout to use since it used to not be relevant until constraint layout was implemented.

Comment: `it is not a bug` but simply swallowing the text and making it disappear without explanation is hardly good design of a UI tool.

Comment: Yeah but that is still not a bug its an intended feature. If the user knows what kind of layout he is using this should never be an issue. Though it would be nice if there was a message letting you know why is that happening, but the UI itself isnt meant for teaching new users.